# How to indent the second line of paragraph in a numbered list

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

I am currently using Office365. I came across a problem: I have a numbered paragraph like this:

1. Function App - Azure Functions allows you to run small pieces of code (called "functions") without worrying about application infrastructure. A function is "triggered" by a specific type of event.  Supported triggers include responding to changes in data, responding to messages, running on a schedule, or as the result of an HTTP request.

I would like to indent the second line and respective lines like this:

```
1.  Function App - Azure Functions allows you to run small pieces of code (called "functions") without 
                   worrying about application infrastructure. A function is "triggered" by a specific 
                   type of event.  Supported triggers include responding to changes in data, responding 
                   to messages, running on a schedule, or as the result of an HTTP request.
```

How do I achieve this? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just adjust the [hanging indent for the paragraph.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-hanging-indent-7bdfb86a-c714-41a8-ac7a-3782a91ccad5)

Comment: @DavidPostill I tried that and it is indenting the paragraph as a whole

Comment: Then you are not doing it correctly. There will already a hanging indent if it is a list. You need to drag it to the right in the formatting ruler.

Comment: If i drag the hanging indent on the ruler to the right, it is moving the whole paragraph to the right

Comment: You dragging the wrong marker. There is a first line marker which changes the left indent of the paragraph and a hanging indent marker which changes the second and subsequent lines. See [Setting Paragraph Indents | Formatting Documents in Word 2013 | InformIT](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2030049&seqNum=13)

Comment: In a numbered list, indents cannot be changed in paragraph formatting. They have to be changed in the list. See my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

- Right-click the paragraph and select "Paragraph..."
- You should be positioned on the tab "Indents and Spacing"
- Under "Indentation", below "Special" you should find "Hanging" to be selected
- Increase the value below "By:"
- Click OK
- If the indentation is not enough, repeat the above.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is almost a year old but I figured I would provide the answer I came up with. There has been a lot of people that seem to not understand what is wanted. I ran into this problem recently and all answers I had found did not address this as it seemed a canned answer was given for using hanging indents, and not bothering to understand that the numbering format uses the default hanging indent to indent the lines after the number and is not able to indent subsequent lines an extra indent. As per your example this seems to be what you wanted. By trial and error and incorporating other suggestions, I was able to find a solution that worked for me.

First create your number list with some information, for example using your example ( I used a short line followed by ... to indicate line continues because depending on size of screen it will format this differently):

[image: original]

Now right click anywhere on the paragraph and choose “Adjust Line Indents” from popup menu. On the Adjust List Indents window look for “Text indent” and change to something like1”, this can be changed later, now find “Follow number with:” field and change it from “Tab character” to “Nothing” and click “OK”. This will format the line to look like this:

[image]

Format Changed, but has First line next to number

Now create a tab stop where you want the first line to start, for example at .5”, only suggest this because when you get to higher numbers that contain more digits like 10 or 100 your lines will no longer line up, now put your cursor at the first position before your first word, in front of the F in Function in this case, and press CTRL+Tab, this will tab the beginning of the line to your tab stop. Now like the others suggest you can go to adjust the Hanging position from either the ruler at the top of page or right click paragraph, choose paragraph from the menu, on the Indents and Spacing tab in the Indentation segment, Special should say Hanging, and under By: adjust number to where you want the hanging lines to start.

Don't forget after each time you hit Enter for a new number press CTRL+Tab to indent your first line away from the number

[image]

Formatted better

Answer (score 0):

### You need to change the Text Indent in the Define New MultiLevel List dialog!

This is true even though you are using a simple list to start with.

Follow the directions in Shauna Kelly's [Creating Outline Numbering](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html). Shu uses the built-in heading styles but you can do this with any existing paragraph style. The key is that this dialog allows you to set indents in numbering.

[image: screenshot of dialog]

This used to be available for flat lists but no longer is, so far as I know. Here is [my numbering article's section dealing with this](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/numbering.htm#Customizing).

Here is a [temporary link to a document](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7bccoibepmjgreg/deleteme%20numbering%20indent.docx?dl=0) with this set up.

[image: screenshot from sample document]